# Display Records sequentially by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once again I have a problem.

So I have a table, that looks like this:
First Example:

```
InstitutionalReportRecordsID            |StringValue    |StringEntryNumber  |Description    |DeleteBit
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    01/14/2015          0                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    12/10/2014          0                 ThisYearTermB   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                1                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                1                 ThisYearTermB   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                2                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                2                 ThisYearTermB   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                3                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                3                 ThisYearTermB   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                4                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    NULL                4                 ThisYearTermB   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    3A15                5                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    2B15                5                 ThisYearTermB   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    3A15                5                 ThisYearTermA   0
A1E16CCA-1120-43A8-B562-3AE0794CFEE5    2B15                5                 ThisYearTermB   0
```

This table stores Data based on Description, and String Entry number. They act as an X and Y coordinate for displaying the StringValue column.

The output should look like this when all is said and done:

Second Example:

```
Descrip         ReportDate  DataColumnOne   DataColumnTwo   DataColumnThree Counts  Comment
ThisYearTermA   11/12/2014  NULL             NULL           NULL            NULL    2A15
ThisYearTermB   12/10/2014  NULL             NULL           NULL            NULL    2B15
```

Here is what is happening. I am taking a report, and I have to shove it into a table that corresponds to the first code example above. I then need to take and create a job to auto email one of our Business Intelligence folks a SQL Blob that matches the Second Example, so that she can put it into Excel, and email it around the company.

I am somewhat shoving a square peg into a round hold here. If I had been able to create a new set of tables for this, then everything would have been much easier, not to mention it would have corresponded better to how we store and maintain things currently. Sadly, I was told no.

So far in my manipulations, I have been unable to write a select statement to get the output to match the Second Example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what makes up your ReportDate, count, DataColumnOne/two/three columns based on your input set?

Comment: They are defined by the source sproc(You don't really want to see that). Before they get to this point though, I set them as Varchar(50) though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? The comment fields didn't really make sense since the values don't match the table, but maybe max / min from the values work.

```
select
  Description,
  max(convert(datetime, case when StringEntryNumber = 0 then StringValue else NULL end, 101)) as ReportDate,
  max(case when StringEntryNumber = 1 then StringValue else NULL) as DataColumnOne,
  max(case when StringEntryNumber = 2 then StringValue else NULL) as DataColumnTwo,
  max(case when StringEntryNumber = 3 then StringValue else NULL) as DataColumnThree,
  max(case when StringEntryNumber = 4 then StringValue else NULL) as Counts,
  max(case when StringEntryNumber = 5 then StringValue else NULL) as Comment
from
  table
group by
  Description
```

Comment: This is close. Oddly, this is having the same issue I was having earlier where the "Comments Column" is being put into its own row, instead of tacked on at the end. I will play with it though

Comment: If it's a separate row, then there must be something wrong with the Description field value, since this query should return just one row per Description.

Comment: No worries, with just a slight bit of tweaking I got it to work perfectly. Thank you for your help, I was going down a totally different path, and this is what I needed.